# How can I quickly send an MS Outlook meeting invite to all the members of a Slack DM group?

Tags: outlook.com, slack

I have to send an MS Outlook meeting invite to all the members of a Slack DM group. How can I quickly do so? I don't want to have to copy paste member name/email one by one.

If this helps, MS Outlook uses the same LDAP as Slack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Slack DM group, go to Settings >  Copy member email addresses:

[image]

then paste into the  MS Outlook meeting invite.